# SmtpClient.Send not working on linux environment

Tags: c#, linux, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-2.0

The following code, written in the `.net core 2` environment, works in `the windows environment` but not in `the linux environment`.

```
string host = "10.99.99.10";
int port = 25;
string userName = "user@user.com";
string password = "password";
string from = userName;

var client = new SmtpClient
{
    Host = host,
    Port = port,
    EnableSsl = false,
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false,
    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password)
};

MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage();
mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(from);
mailMessage.To.Add(userName);
mailMessage.Body = "This is test mail.";
mailMessage.Subject = "Testing";                
client.Send(mailMessage);
```

Exception: `Failure sending mail.`

InnerExcepiton:

```
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): GSSAPI operation failed with error - An invalid status code was supplied (Unknown error).
   at System.Net.Security.NegotiateStreamPal.AcquireCredentialsHandle(String package, Boolean isServer, NetworkCredential credential)
   at System.Net.NTAuthentication.Initialize(Boolean isServer, String package, NetworkCredential credential, String spn, ContextFlagsPal requestedContextFlags, ChannelBinding channelBinding)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpNtlmAuthenticationModule.Authenticate(String challenge, NetworkCredential credential, Object sessionCookie, String spn, ChannelBinding channelBindingToken)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.SetContextAndTryAuthenticate(ISmtpAuthenticationModule module, NetworkCredential credential, ContextAwareResult context)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpConnection.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpTransport.GetConnection(String host, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.GetConnection()
   at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
```

StackTrace:

```
at System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send(MailMessage message)
   at MyProject.Helper.Utils.SendMail() in C:\Test\MyProject\MyProject.Helper\Utils.cs:line 146
```

Linux:    `Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS`

This is a console app. 
Why is not working in linux environment?

Comment: Your SMTP server might be requiring authentication. Try `telnet 10.99.99.10 25` and try sending a test email using SMTP commands. http://www.samlogic.net/articles/smtp-commands-reference.htm

Comment: @SameerNaik Telnet is working.(10.99.99.10 25)

Comment: The cause of the 0x80004005 error code seems to be a damaged installation. I would try to reinstall .net core. https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/914232/you-may-receive-error-code-0x80004005-or-other-error-codes-when-you-tr

Comment: @ManosPasgiannis I tried, but the problem continues.

Comment: Also, note that MailKit is still the preferred way to send e-mails on .NET Core. Also, it could be one of the problem @Karelz refers to here: https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/12416#issuecomment-330279488

Comment: @BrunoGarcia I tried different combinations but I received wrong certificates or logon errors. MailKit works on windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it was a code error because of the error I had, but it was not. When I gave the `relay authority` on the mail server side my problem was solved. I think it is doing this automatically in windows environment.

**Edit**: Add ip address and allow anonymous user in Receive connectors / Exchange server

Comment: What exactly is relay authority on the mail server?

Comment: @danieltheman I think it sends mail without checking user information like anonymous.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54930686/6468577) out also.